# How can I prove that $\frac{(3^n + 4^n)}{(4^n + 1)}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> How can I prove that $$\frac{(3^n + 4^n)}{(4^n + 1)}$$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is bounded?

Please don't tell me the full answer, I would just like a push in the right direction.

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $4^n\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide both the numerator and denominator by $4^n$. Then your sequence becomes

$$ \frac{(3/4)^n+1}{1+(1/4)^n}$$
Now all the terms raised to power $n$ are in $(0,1)$, and thus, taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ you obtain $1$. A convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: Only 4 minutes to wait for the full answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is another proof which provides bounds and makes use of the following property of numbers:
$$
if\ \ \ (0\leq a\leq X\leq b\ \ \ and\ \ \ 0<c\leq Y\leq d)\ \ \ \ then\ \ \
\ (0\leq \frac{a}{d}\leq \frac{X}{Y}\leq \frac{b}{c})
$$
So since
$$
1\leq 1+\left( \frac{3}{4}\right) ^{n}\leq 1+\left( \frac{3}{4}\right) ^{0}=2
$$
and 
$$
1\leq 1+\left( \frac{1}{4}\right) ^{n}\leq 1+\left( \frac{1}{4}\right) ^{0}=2
$$
then
$$
\frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{1+\left( \frac{3}{4}\right) ^{n}}{1+\left( \frac{1}{4}%
\right) ^{n}}\leq \frac{2}{1},\ for\ any\ n\geq 0.
$$